# Find minimum distance to visit set of disconnected routes

Tags: c#, google-maps, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Let's say I have set of disconnected road routes, like in [this example](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zhOGHJtqy9EQ.kDbCohOvhuJI). Each route has `Start` and `Finish` points, which might be the same (if route is circular). Route can be "open" (different Start/Finish), or "closed" (same Start/Finish). For closed routes it is possible to define exact entry/exit point as Start/Finish point.

Also "global" `START` and `FINISH` points are defined.

How to find minimum "cost" (distance or duration) required to visit all routes, starting from "global" START, passing each route from Start to Finish (or from Finish to Start), and completing journey at "global" FINISH ?

I am familiar with Dijkstra algorithm, but I'm not sure if it can be used in this case.

Distances and/or durations between each two points are known (can be calculated). I guess distance/duration for each route in the set are not important, because we need to find out minimum "cost" of all "interconnection" routes, needed to travel from end of one route to the beginning of next one.

Direction of each route is not important, ie. it is possible to travel each route from Start to Finish, but also from Finish to Start.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the [Traveling salesperson problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is NP-hard. Fortunately, even a greedy approximation should give you okay results and if you need an exact solution, 13! is only 6,227,020,800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the problem right, you are trying to interconnect a set of (start,finish) pairs, starting from a global START node and ending at a global FINISH node, such that the interconnections among those pairs have minimal distance. The connections among the local start and finish points (routes of interest) are already given according to your description, and are thus irrelevant.

As already noted in the comment this problem is NP-hard and thus unsolveable by a polynomial time algorithm (unless P=NP).

As the comment made above suggests, if the local (start,finish) pairs are fairly small in number you could simply try out all permutations of those pairs, and connect those in the order given by the respective permutation, each time using dijkstra (or more advanced p2p-algorithms). Unfortunately as was stated before this is overkill for the 13 pairs in your example.

What you could try, is to heuristically reduce the number of permutations, by considering (greedily) only the next X nearest start points from the last finish point (which can be determined with one run of dijkstra). For X=2 and 13 pairs this would bring you down to 2^12 = 4098 permutations. For X=3, that would be 3^11*2= 354294. The higher X is the better the solution becomes as more permutations are considered, with the drawback of longer computation.